# How to obtain self-updating prices of oil in excel 2007?

Tags: excel

I would love to have actual oil price in one of my excel spreadsheet cell. How can i make such self-actualizing creation?

Best wishes all

Comment: You might try an office/excel forum, or more likely some forum related to oil prices, this Q&A site is strictly for programming questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a website import in excel which can refresh.

1. Find a website where the oil price is provide (the simpler the page, the better)
2. Open a new spread sheet
3. From the Ribbon select Data > From the web (on the left)
4. enter the URL from 1

Comment: But that would import data once and will not self-update in the future, or is it?

Comment: @kasper you can refresh them like any other data source. In the ribbon use Data > Refresh All or press Alt+F5 while inside the webdata

Answer (score 0):

You could use the free FinAnSu add-in (http://code.google.com/p/finansu/), which allows you to plug live quotes from Bloomberg, Google or Yahoo into Excel. It can also retrieve data from a website and parse out a particular piece with a regular expression, which might help if you want to get the price from some other site.